# Android: Building and Loading Custom Kernel onto Nexus One

Tags: android

I have been using this guide: http://darts.cse.nd.edu:8080/Plone/materials/setting-up-android-development, to help me build and load my custom kernel. In my custom kernel, I added my own pre-loaded application, but it never appears when I flash my custom kernel onto my Nexus One. I was wondering if following this guide is the right procedure, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **@Sebastian P:** Really?  He [asked the question at Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5370/buidling-and-loading-custom-kernel-onto-nexus-one) and I was just about to migrate it over here when I found this dupe. Isn't this a programming/development question? **Android.SE is for questions relating to Android use, not development.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little above my paygrade but **I don't believe you can bake an app into the Kernel**.

It's my understanding that the kernel runs under the hood and acts as an intermediary between the hardware and the OS.  To be able to "use" the app instead of it just running in the background I believe you'd have to do this at the ROM level in the OS.

Even if you *can* write an app into the Kernel you'd have to have some customization to the OS for the user to interact with it in the UI and you'd have to flash a whole custom ROM instead of just the Kernel.

*(I may be way off based on this answer because I don't really know anything about programming but this is my understanding from reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html).)*